# Solving recurrence relation t(n) = t(n/2) + log2(n), such that T(1)=0

Tags: recurrence-relation

I get how to solve recurrence relations for t(n)= t(n-1) etc etc.

But how would you solve the recurrence of t(n) = t(n/2) + log2(n), such that T(1)=0? I don't understand how the log would behave in this situation.

Comment: you can solve the recurrence either by direct application of master theorem or you could just recurse  and find out the summation . The summation will look something like this :

T(n) = T(n/2^i) + [log n+log(n /2)+⋯+log(n/2^log n)] .

 you just need to find the sum of the series with the log terms to find the upper bound of the recurrence

Comment: Calculate t (1024), then you can figure it out easily.